# ipset hash: net, iface does not work. When add physical interface ethx to the bridge

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter

```
**Network topology**

PC1<------->eth1:LINUX(PC3):eth2<------>PC2

PC1 ping PC2 , Via PC3
```

As follows:

```
brctl addbr br1
brctl addif br eth1
brctl addif br eth2
```

IPset:

```
ipset create szone hash:net,iface
ipset add szone 0/0,physdev:eth1
ipset create dzone hash:net,iface
ipset add szone 0/0,physdev:eth2
```

Iptables:

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m set --match-set szone src,src -m set --match-set dzone dst,dst -j DROP
```

And then,in fact, iptabels rule not work.why? and I have loaded br_netfilter.ko

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Note that pkts generated by the box itself do not go through the `FORWARD` chain. So the ping test as shown is not going to hit that iptables rule.So either your rule is wrong or the test is wrong.

Comment: There are three PCs in total.